# Force acting on a negative particle in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, particle-physics, magnetic-fields

I have recently learned about magnetic fields and particles. The recent one I have learnt is the right hand rule. The force F acting on a negative particle is always opposite to the force we get from the right hand rule, if I understand the right hand rule correctly. An exercise in my book said that I was wrong about this, so I'll ask from the physisists here.

[image]
My school book says that the force acting on the negative particle in c) will go towards left. That would be correct if the particle was positive, right? As I understand things the force acting on the negative particle is towards right?

edit: I would appreciate if I could get a second opinion/answer here.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{V} × \vec{B}$ follows the right hand rule, where:

$\vec{V}$ is pointer finger.

$\vec{B}$ is the middle finger.
[image]

Pointer finger down, middle finger into the page, would result in the force being to the right,
.

Multiply by a negative means the force is towards the left.

Comment: Wait, how do you get that result? when my middle finger is pointing into the page and index finger down then my thumb points to the left. Then, shouldn't the force be then to the right?

Comment: if you have used your right hand, it should point right. Hence the force is left.

Comment: Look at the image  to help,